# How to complete this Prüfer Code?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working on an unassessed course problem,

> Draw the tree with Prüfer Code $2,7,1,8,2,8,1,8$.

The code has length $|(2,7,1,8,2,8,1,8)|=8=n-2$ so the tree should have $n=8+2=10$ vertices. When I try to fill in table I get $$\begin{matrix}2&7&1&8&2&8&1&8&10\\3&4&5&6&7&2&8&1&9\end{matrix}$$ but this leave the edge $\{9,10\}$ disconnected from the rest of the tree. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is here:

\begin{matrix}2&7&1&8&2&8&1&8&10\\
3&4&5&6&7&2&\color{red}{8}\end{matrix}

The number you're filling in here is the number of the vertex deleted at the $7^{\text{th}}$ stage of the iterative process "delete the smallest-numbered leaf". Vertices $2,3,4,5,6,7$ have been deleted already, so they cannot be deleted again. Vertices $1,8,10$ are also ruled out, because they still appear in the top row: they are not leaves at this stage! Only vertex $9$ is a leaf, so it is the correct number to fill in.

Correcting this mistake, we get

\begin{matrix}2&7&1&8&2&8&1&8&10\\
3&4&5&6&7&2&\color{blue}9&\color{blue}1 & \color{blue}8\end{matrix}

which gives the edges of a $10$-vertex tree.